# How to get SelectedValue from a DropDownList in DetailsView UpdatePanel?

Tags: updatepanel, detailview, dropdownlistfor

I am using an UpdatePanel to DetailsView, where I have a DropDonwList in it. The DropDownList work find in DetailView, but I cannot get the Selected Value from the DropDownList in my Code-Behind file. Here are the ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate> 
<asp:DetailsView ID="detailsView_User" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
  DefaultMode="Insert">
  <Fields>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="User Name" SortExpression="Name" ControlStyle-Width="200" />

  <asp:TemplateField>
    <InsertItemTemplate>          
      <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownList_Agency" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllAgency" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropDownList_Agency_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList><br />
      <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownList_Department" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllDepartment" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList><br />

      <asp:Button ID="button_Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="button_Cancel_Click"/>
      <asp:Button ID="button_CreateUser" runat="server" Text="Create User"/>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 </Fields>

</asp:DetailsView>
      </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
      <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="detailsView_User" /> 
    </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I try to the the SelectedValue

```
dropDownList_Agency.SelectedValue;
```

I get this error: The name 'dropDownList_Agency' does not exist in the current context
I do not know why. Do you have an idea to a solution?

Comment: I have just try this: 'label_Message.Text = detailsView_User.SelectedValue.ToString();' but I got a System.NullReferenceException:

Answer (score 0):

For the selected Value you need to use IndexOf:

```
myDropDown.SelectedIndex = 
myDropDown.Items.IndexOf(myDropDown.Items.FindByValue("myValue"))
```